# Yii params not working

Tags: parameters, yii

I'm new at Yii and I'm using the `findAllBySql` function to get some records.

```
$users = User::model()->findAllBySql("
  SELECT * 
  FROM users u 
  WHERE replace(lower(u.firstname),' ','') LIKE '%:s%' 
     OR replace(lower(u.lastname),' ','') LIKE '%:s%'",
  array(':s' => $search)
);
```

If I hardcode the value of :s, the function works correctly so it seems like Yii isn't changing the parameter `:s`. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Thijs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$users = User::model()->findAllBySql("
  SELECT * 
  FROM users u 
  WHERE replace(lower(u.firstname),' ','') LIKE :s 
     OR replace(lower(u.lastname),' ','') LIKE :s",
  array(':s' => '%' . $search . '%')
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now! Can you also explain why my method wasn't working?

Comment: It was just a syntax error.  [Parameter binding in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#binding-parameters) is built on [PHP's binding](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#binding-parameters).  Quotations are not expected and parameters are of the form `:name`.  Basically, just use `:name`, and then define that there.  Yours might have worked without the quotations, but I'm not sure.